# Can't cabal install hunit

Tags: haskell, cabal, hunit

Very new to the Haskell ecosystem here. I'm trying to install hunit but when I run `cabal install hunit` I get the following message:

```
Warning: The install command is a part of the legacy v1 style of cabal usage.

Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-install
command or the legacy v1-install alias as new-style projects will become the
default in the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot
replicate a working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

cabal: There is no package named 'hunit'. However, the following package name
exists: 'HUnit'.
```

Answer (score 6):

This message is telling you two different things.  "Install" is a legacy command and "hunit" does not exist.

Your short solution is `cabal v2-install --lib HUnit`.
For a legacy behavior consider `cabal v1-install HUnit`.

**install is legacy: The big paragraph**

Cabal used to install everything into a single store, either user or system wide, and if any package ever disagreed on package version then good luck.  The v2 commands move to a "nix style build" where different versions can co-exist in the store and projects can continue to benefit by sharing builds for common packages.  The v2 commands are literally the commands prefixed with `v2-`, such as `v2-install`, `v2-build` and `v2-configure`.

**hunit does not exist**

Hackage is case sensitive.  The tool already informed you that you might have intended to install `HUnit` instead of `hunit`.

**Epilog: Use `--lib`**

The `v2-install` does not expose the built libraries unless installed explicitly via `--lib`.  This reduces namespace clutter at some expensive of us programmers needing to retrain.  To use HUnit as a library and play with it in the repl, add `--lib` as shown at the beginning.